# Storing the return type of function called inside closure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store the result of a function call in `r`. However, I get that the type `R` may not live long enough

```
use std::sync::Arc;

pub type OnVirtualTunWrite = Arc<dyn Fn(Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8])> , usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;

struct A {
    on_virtual_tun_write: OnVirtualTunWrite
}

impl A {
    fn consume<R, F>(self, len: usize, f: F) -> Result<R,()>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) ->  Result<R,()>,
    {
        let r: Result<R,()>;
        let result = (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(|b: &mut [u8]| {
            r = f(b);
        }), len);
        r
    }
}
```

Error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0310]: the parameter type `R` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:15:50
   |
10 |     fn consume<R, F>(self, len: usize, f: F) -> Result<R,()>
   |                - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `R: 'static`
...
15 |         let result = (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(|b: &mut [u8]| {
   |                                                  ^^^^^^^^ ...so that the reference type `&mut std::result::Result<R, ()>` does not outlive the data it points at

error[E0310]: the parameter type `R` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:15:50
   |
10 |       fn consume<R, F>(self, len: usize, f: F) -> Result<R,()>
   |                  - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `R: 'static`
...
15 |           let result = (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(|b: &mut [u8]| {
   |  __________________________________________________^
16 | |             r = f(b);
17 | |         }), len);
   | |__________^ ...so that the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:15:59: 17:10]` will meet its required lifetime bounds

error[E0310]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:15:50
   |
10 |       fn consume<R, F>(self, len: usize, f: F) -> Result<R,()>
   |                     - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `F: 'static`
...
15 |           let result = (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(|b: &mut [u8]| {
   |  __________________________________________________^
16 | |             r = f(b);
17 | |         }), len);
   | |__________^ ...so that the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:15:59: 17:10]` will meet its required lifetime bounds

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a610b15f48c8217274a75a4d03c76380

Let me begin by this error:

```
so that the reference type `&mut std::result::Result<R, ()>` does not outlive the data it points at
```

Why a reference? `f` returns `std::result::Result<R, ()>`, not a reference. So I don't see why it treats it like a mutable reference.

Also, as I can crearly see, `r` lives more than the `Box` and the closure inside the `Box`

Answer (score 0):

> Why a reference?

The closure is capturing `r` by reference; you could avoid it by using the `move` keyword. However, you *want* it to be a reference since you still want to use it afterwards.

---

A big constraint causing your problems stems from the fact that trait objects are `'static` by default. This is specifically a problem since the boxed closure you want to pass to `on_virtual_tun_write` has references (which are not `'static`), which is why you get the errors you see.

You can fix this by making the inner trait generic over any lifetime.

```
pub type OnVirtualTunWrite = Arc<dyn for<'a> Fn(Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]) + 'a>, usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;
                                  // ^^^^^^^                              ^^^^
```

Fixing this problem exposes others though:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `r`, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:16:13
   |
14 |         let r: Result<R,()>;
   |             - help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut r`
15 |         let result = (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(|b: &mut [u8]| {
16 |             r = f(b);
   |             ^ cannot assign

error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `r`
  --> src/lib.rs:15:59
   |
15 |         let result = (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(|b: &mut [u8]| {
   |                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `r`
16 |             r = f(b);
   |             - borrow occurs due to use in closure
```

You cannot capture a potentially uninitialized value in a closure. A common way to fix this is to use `Option`:

```
let mut r: Option<Result<R,()>> = None;
let result = (self.on_virtual_tun_write)(Box::new(|b: &mut [u8]| {
    r = Some(f(b));
}), len);
r.unwrap()
```

This also covers the potential problem that `on_virtual_tun_write` may not even call the given function needed to initialize `r`. As I've presented, it would panic in that case, but handling that issue would be up to you.